# Term for conversational actions meant to influence emotional state

Tags: psycholinguistics

Is there a term for the set of conversational actions/tools that instead of exchanging direct information, seek to instead affect a certain emotional state?
Examples of such actions would include compliments, taunts, threats, (to express) doubt, etc.
Is there any branch of linguists that studies this aspect of verbal communication?

Comment: Pragmatics is the branch of linguistics that studies this. There are some cover terms, like _impositive_, which covers all types of speech that try to impose the speaker's will on the addressee, like ordering, questioning, directing, insisting, etc.

Comment: Speech act theory, to a certain extent.

Comment: I'm not sure whether [Rhetoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric) can be subsumed under linguistics, but there you can find a wealth of well-known and named techniques to affect the emotional state of the recipients of verbal communication.

Comment: Yes, pragmatics, and theatre, darling, which studies the gestures that often accompany emotional states.

Comment: Rhetoric overlaps with pragmatics in many ways. In N. America it's found in Speech and Drama departments while pragmatics is found in Linguistics departments. Sometimes they talk to one another. Similar remarks on phonetics, dialectology, and sociolinguistics in one department, while voice coaching and accent mimicry is in a different one.

Answer (score 2):

In J. L. Austin's speech act theory, complimenting, persuading, frightening, and so on are termed *perlocutionary acts*: the effect of the speech on other people. Note that unintentional effects also fall into this category: if I say something innocuous that causes you to feel afraid, I've frightened you (a perlocutionary act), whether or not that was my intent.

This is contrasted with *locutionary acts* (the actual words you say and their literal meanings) and *illocutionary acts* (the implications of those words).

Austin's theory, and various alternatives to it, generally fall under the heading of *pragmatics*.